# How to share faust table between multiple agents or faust timers?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, faust

I'm trying to publish faust table's data(count) to a kafka topic after some time interval. timer is working when I publish some simple string, but it is not able to access table's data somehow. 
Following is the code for timer:

```py
@app.timer(interval=10.0)
async def publish_to_anomaly_topic():
            await anomaly_topic.send(
            value=str(page_views['total'].value())
          )
@app.agent(page_view_topic)
async def count_page_views(views):
    async for view in views.group_by(PageView.id):
        total=0
        page_views[view.id]+=1
        for everykey in list(page_views.keys()):
            if everykey != 'total':
                total+=page_views[everykey].value()
        page_views['total'] = total
```

The agent is working fine. I am able to see the values correctly.

Comment: could you please share the error or the malfunction you came up with? just for understanding the mechanism of Faust. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of experiments, it turned out that you can't access table's values along with the app timer(even if you specify [relative_field](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tables.html#id6) option while creating table). A workaround for this problem is to create another table to maintain timestamps of your messages and use them in your business logic.

```
   if view.timestamp-page_views_timer[view.id+'_first_timestamp'] > 60:
         await anomaly_topic.send(value={//the data to be sent})
```

where page_views_timer is the new table created.

Answer (score 2):

Found this question in my attempts to do the same thing and here is how I was able to figure it out.

https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/tables.html

> You cannot modify a table outside of a stream operation; this means
> that you can only mutate **the table from within an async for event in**
> **stream: block.** We require this to align the table’s partitions with
> the stream’s, and to ensure the source topic partitions are correctly
> rebalanced to a different worker upon failure, along with any
> necessary table partitions.
>
> Modifying a table outside of a stream will raise an error:

The documentation says that you are not able to access/modify the table outside of a stream operation.

To get around this you can split your timer function into 2 parts:

```
@app.timer(10)
async def my_timer_function():
    # value does not matter as much as the send operation
    await my_calling_function.send(value="send data now!") 

@app.agent()
async def my_calling_function(stream_from_timer_func):
    async for message in stream_from_timer_func:
        print(message) # this will print "send data now!"
        table_data = my_table['key']
        # Here is where you can access your table data and finish sending the 
        # message to the topic you want
        await my_topic.send(value=table_data)
```

As you can see if you use the timer function to send a message to an agent, you are able to access the table you want, it just has to be in an

```
async for event in stream:
```

block of code.

Comment: thank you sir, very elegant solution :) feels like something that would fit well to Faust's cookbook in the docs